# Splitting class definition into multiple module units in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Is there any way to split class definition (implementation) into more than one module unit? It can be helpful in case if one or more class's methods are big enough to be placed in separate source files.
The best solution I see could be class declaration in module interface file and one of its methods definition in separate module implementation file. But it doesn't work because compiler doesn't see class declaration compiling module implementation file:

```
//module interface unit
export module test;
export class foo
{
   void f();
};

//module implementation unit
module test;
void foo::f() {} // compiler doesn't know about foo class and its methods
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to split code into main.cpp header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123609/how-to-split-code-into-main-cpp-header-file)

Comment: Are you asking about C++20 modules, or just regular source file organization?

Comment: What you’ve written should work (although that’s not “multiple modules”); this is a problem in your compilation environment.

Comment: @DavisHerring, you are right about wrong terminology I used in my question: not multiple modules, but multiple module units

Comment: @DavisHerring, yes it works. You're right: that was a problem in my compilation environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thanks to everyone answering my question. The example published in my initial question works. As I wrote in one of my answers to Davis Herring (thank you, Davis, for correcting class method's name in my example) the problem was in my compiling environment. There is absolutely no need to use module partitions to solve this issue - they are for different purposes (for example, for dealing with libraries).

Answer (score 5):

Module.ixx

```
export module foolib;
export import :foo;
export import :fooimpl;
export import :fooimpl2;
```

foo.ixx

```
export module foolib:foo;
export class foo
{
public:
    void hello1();
    void hello2();
};
```

fooimpl1.ixx

```
export module foolib:fooimpl;
import :foo;
void foo::hello1() {}
```

fooimpl2.ixx

```
export module foolib:fooimpl2;
import :foo;
void foo::hello2() {}
```

Comment: There is no need to use module partitions to solve my problem. Did you try to compile example published in my question before posting your answer? If yes, you have to admit that it actually works without any changes. But thank you anyway for showing others another way of using modules standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about module *partitions*.  A single module can be split up into more than one source file by making each one separate module, but those submodules are recognised as such and put back together into a single named module automatically.

The syntax of a *partition* is a colon and the subname.

```
module foo:part1;
```

You can read more about it here: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/10/modules-1.html

> Just like with C++ headers, there is no requirement that modules be split and subdivided into multiple files. Nevertheless, large source files can become intractable, so C++ modules also have a way to subdivide a single module into distinct translation units that are merged together to form the total module. These subdivisions are known as partitions.

Comment: Does it help to split _class implementation_ amount multiple module units (or as you suggesting, multiple module partitions)? There are no examples of the subj at all (at least I can't find any)

Comment: A module partition is not a “separate module” to be “put back together”; it is a facility for letting one part of a module import another (which is *similar* to being a another module in that it can be imported).  There’s no need *a priori* to use them for separating the definitions of a class’s member functions.

Comment: @AndyX: "Help" in what way? Partitions exist mainly for user-convenience. If you find it convenient to divide your implementation in such a way, you can do that. Just remember that partitions still need their inclusion graph to be acyclic, and it can be pretty easy to create a cycle.